# What's the difference between using RDFS/OWL versus a tagging/markup language that uses tags?

Tags: tags, metadata, semantic-web, semantic-markup, ontology

Mainly, I was wondering what advantages the ontology languages of RDFS/OWL has over using a tagging/markup system (such as http://www.schema.org/) for managing and creating metadata?

Answer (score 2):

This question is a duplicate of [What's the difference between using RDFS/OWL and XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711597/whats-the-difference-between-using-rdfs-owl-and-xml), which has been then [posted at answers.semanticweb.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20140627131016/http://answers.semanticweb.com:80/questions/15215/whats-the-difference-between-using-rdfsowl-versus-xml) and answered there.